# Need a tool to sync data between computer and external HDD in linux

Tags: linux, sync, kde

I'm looking for a tool similar to synctoy in linux. For those who dont know what synctoy does is... its a simple syncing application that allows you to copy your data between multiple hard drives and keeps all copies in sync with the latest data.
I'm specifically looking for KDE based tool if KDE based is not available then my second preference will be for gtk based app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard tool for bidirectional synchronization is probably unison, which has a gtk frontend.

Comment: Will it allow me to sync data between USB harddisk and laptop? I've used unison in past but I remember it using only to sync data between multiple machines.

Comment: Yes, you can also synchronize two directories or hard disks on your own computer.

Answer (score 2):

For anything Linux based I'd always recommend rsync. Since you prefer a graphical tool, you might enjoy the [**Setara**](http://setara.org/) graphical frontend for KDE :)

[image]

It will also tell you the commands as it runs, which I find handy if you plan to write scripts that do similar tasks in the future if the tool is not available...

[image]

Also, the good old [**Krsync**](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Krsync?content=68586) frontend:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I had to put lot of effort to install krsync however it does not work the way I expected. It seems it only does syncing in one direction.